# need to do the conversion of an id to a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I'm working on a simple application that receives from two other tables (books and people) a join table with two objects: books_id and people_id. I made all the settings as above and only in this table the label was not replaced by the contents in the case would be the id. I think at its id a number that is already happening in outrass tables that work with string. In the vision I equaled my label.text my rope, but in this case label.text should not pass anything because it is not only the number and no text. How should I proceed?

```
#import "LeiturasViewController.h"

@interface LeiturasViewController ()

@end

@implementation LeiturasViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.people_id.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.pessoa_id];
    self.book_id.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.book_id];

}


@end
```

Comment: please clarify your question. what is pessoa_id and livro_id. What have you tried. Post some code.

Comment: is pessoa_id a label?

Comment: not I get pessoa_id api. It is an id of an object in the table. I want to change it to replace a label in a view in the app

Comment: people_id and person_id are the same, just forgot to translate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got your question right cause it's not very clear but I believe this is what you need

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", pessoa_id];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried what to do you recommended however instead of appearing the id appeared this <UILabel: 0x7fd74fd89323d; frame = ...

Comment: English please! what's this?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 

{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *peple = (NSString*) self.pessoa_id;
    NSString *book = (NSString*) self.book_id;

    self.people_id.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", peple];
    self.book_id.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", book];

}
```